# execlp() failing to retrieve correct input

Tags: c, pipe, fork, dup

I've been trying to write a really simple program in which the parent process passes 100 lines to a child process through a pipe. The child should then use the generated lines and execute the command line program `more` over those lines. 
However, when I try to run the program, it just freezes. I was careful to close all descriptors not being used by both processes but I don't really understand what may be causing it.

Code:

```
int main(void){

    int fd[2];
    if (pipe(fd) == -1){
        perror("Error creating pipe");
        return 1;
    }

    dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
        printf("Line %d\n", i);
    }
    close(fd[1]);

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0) {
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);

        execlp("more", "more",(char*) NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute 'more'\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    wait(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're on `Linux` run your program under `strace` and see that it does not actually freeze, it works correctly and ends with `wait()`.  You just don't see the output - notice what file descriptor `write()` uses.

Comment: I thought it "froze" given that the prompt never appeared after executing it. But why does the output not appear? What can be done to avoid that type of behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was careful to close all descriptors not being used by both processes

Not really.

```
dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
```

Here you make `stdout` a copy of `fd[1]`.

```
close(fd[1]);
```

Here you close `fd[1]`, but `stdout` is still open.

Then you `fork`. At this point both processes have access to the write end of the pipe via `stdout`.

```
    dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(fd[0]);
```

In the child process you copy `fd[0]` to `stdin` and close `fd[0]`.

Then, when you exec `more`, it still has access to both ends of the pipe (via `stdin` / `stdout`).

At the same time your parent process has access to both ends of the pipe (via `fd[0]` / `stdout`).

In effect you've closed nothing.

There's a second issue: Your parent process writes to `stdout`, which is bound to the write end of the pipe, without anyone reading it. Depending on how much you write, whether `stdout` is line buffered or block buffered, how big the `stdout` buffer is, and how much your pipe itself can store, this itself can deadlock. If the pipe runs full and there's no one around to read from it, `printf` will just block.

---

To fix this, don't `dup2` in the parent process and don't write to the pipe before the child process has started.

```
int main(void){
    int fd[2];
    if (pipe(fd) == -1){
        perror("Error creating pipe");
        return 1;
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("Error spawning process");
        return 2;
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        close(fd[1]);  /* close write end of the pipe in the child */
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);

        execlp("more", "more", (char*)NULL);

        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute 'more'\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    close(fd[0]);  /* close read end of the pipe in the parent */

    FILE *fp = fdopen(fd[1], "w");
    if (!fp) {
        perror("Error opening file handle");
        return 3;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
        fprintf(fp, "Line %d\n", i);
    }
    fclose(fp);  /* flush and close write end of the pipe in the parent */

    wait(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and the detailed response! So what was happening was that the output of "more" was being redirected to the writing end of the pipe? And hence Why I couldn't see the output?
And about the second issue: I was not aware of what you described but I'll try to keep that in mind in the future!

Comment: @Pedro Yes, `more`'s `stdout` being redirected to the pipe is one part of the issue and explains why you don't see any output on the terminal. The other issue is that because `more` itself is holding its `stdout` open, it will never see EOF on its `stdin` (because they both refer to the same pipe), so it can never exit.

Comment: glad I was able to learn something new! Thank you once again!